# Why ubuntu uses base 10 for calculating file sizes?

Tags: nautilus, file-size

I understand that hard drive companies do it to market a 900GB HD as an 1TB one, but what is the reason that Nautilus uses base 10 as well?

Shouldn't we try to be right rather than handy?

Comment: This should be a bug report rather than a question the community of users can answer. Any answer we can provide will be opinion based. See [Don't Ask section of the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I need an opinion. I think that there is a logical reason behind it.

Comment: Perhaps what is needed is to [report properly the measurement unit](http://zapatopi.net/labs/kibioctets.html)?

Comment: This isn't an opinion-based question, it has an answer. The question I linked to has a link to the policy along with the rationale, etc.

Comment: "I understand that hard drive companies do it to market a 900GB HD as an 1TB one"  No they don't.  Windows displays the units incorrectly.